# Ajax Post to Controller Action

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

How to call an Action within a Controller in Laravel 4?! I tried it like this:

```
$.post('/tutorials/rate', {id:tutID, rating : rating});
```

in my controller i have this:

```
public function rate()  {
return whatever;
}
```

and in my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/tutorials/rate', array('uses' => 'TutorialController@rate'));
```

But it isn´t workin....

UPDATE: fixed it by myself...changed my controller function to:

```
public function post_rate() {
return whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting via Jquery, but then utilizing a Route::get method in Laravel.

Should be Route::post()

or

Route

```
Route::Controller('tutorials');
```

Controller Tutorials

```
public function postRate(){}
```

Comment: You can also use a controller and do Route::Controller('tutorials'); and then public function postRate() in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You use `$.post()` which means you are sending data using POST request.
You are not catching this method/url combination.

Modify your `routes.php` and you are good to go

```
Route::post('tutorials/rate', 'Tutorials@rate');

<?php

class Tutorials extends BaseController
{
    public function rate()
    {
        return 'rating';
    }
}
```

If I were you, I would use Resource (or maybe RESTfull) controllers.
But it depends on situation - good luck :)

Comment: Hmm, get´s me a 500 Internal Server Error!

Comment: I made the mistake in function name. Fixed, renamed `public function route()` to `public function rate()`. Works now?

Comment: Nah, that Mistake i saw before you fixed it...still not working :(

Comment: Double checked (even unit tested) - works like a charm. Try to run `composer dump-autoload -o` command to reaload class map